# Doubts about standard normal random variable in Ross 'A first Course in Probability'

Tags: probability, random-variables

The book introduces the standard normal random variable in this way:

An important fact about normal random variables is that if X is normally distributed with parameters μ and $\sigma^2$ , then $Y = aX + b$ is normally distributed with
parameters $aμ + b$ and $a^2σ^2$. To prove this statement, suppose that $a > 0$. (The proof
when $a < 0$ is similar.) Let $Fy$ denote the cumulative distribution function of $Y$. Then

$Fy(x) = P (Y ≤ x ) = P(aX + b ≤ x) = P(X ≤\frac{x − b}{a}) = Fx(\frac{x − b}{a})$

where $Fx$ is the cumulative distribution function of $X$. By differentiation, the density function of $Y$ is then

$fy(x) = \frac{1}{a}fx(\frac{x − b}{a}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt(2π)aσ} exp(-(\frac{x − b}{a} − μ)^2/2σ^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt(2π)aσ} exp(-(x-b-aμ)^2/2(aσ)^2)$

which shows that $Y$ is normal with parameters $aμ + b$ and $a^2σ^2$.

An important implication of the preceding result is that if $X$ is normally distributed
with parameters $μ$ and $σ^2$, then $Z = (X − μ)/σ$ is normally distributed with parameters 0 and 1. Such a random variable is said to be a standard, or a unit, normal random variable.

I don't understand the connection between the previous result and standard normal random variable.

Comment: $Z=aX+b$, where $a=\frac{1}{\sigma}$ and $b=-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}$.